# Rational Links and Conway Normal Form

Tags: knot-theory

Is it true that a link is rational if and only if it has a diagram of the form $C(p_{1},...,p_{n})$ ?

Comment: Actually I know the answer to this is yes, as it is stated implicitly in a book I am reading, but if someone has a reference to a proof or their own explanation ...